# ¿Como desarrollar una arquitectura Frontend orientada a consumir microservicios?

Tags: angular, webservice, arquitectura-de-software

Se está desarrollando una arquitectura de micro servicios para ser consumidos por una aplicación que deberá contener 3 grandes módulos: Bancos, Personas y Nomina. El caso es que si los micro servicios sirven para garantizar la disponibilidad de los demás servicios que no están en mantenimiento, ¿como hacer para replicar este principio también en el frontend? En concreto, la pregunta sería ¿Como desarrollar una arquitectura frontend para que al tirar un módulo, estén disponibles los demás y operen de manera normal?

Hasta ahorita lo que sé es que la tecnología para el frontend será Angular 6+

Desde ya, gracias!

Comment: la pregunta parece estar basada en opiniones, lo cual es motivo de cierre; por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 2):

No, microservicios no es para garantizar disponibilidad.
La principal caracteristica es Modularidad.
  A eso agregale, mejor entendimiento del codigo, mantenimiento, independencia en ejecucion, pruebas independientes.

En tu aplicacion web no se tiran modulos sino que se encuentran en un mismo host. Tu aplicacion por Modulos, puedes agregarlos a medida que crece tu aplicacion o reutilizarlos.

Para angular debes identificar no solo los modulos sino que elementos reutilizar,
servicios, directivas, elementos, componentes...

Comment: Es correcto Miguel, gracias por la corrección..
Justo por eso, se ocupa crear, velo de esta forma, una aplicación que contenga aplicaciones que puedan replegarse y desplegarse sin afectar a las demás
[https://blog.pragmatists.com/independent-micro-frontends-with-single-spa-library-a829012dc5be]
algo como lo que hacen en este post pero con puro Angular 6+

Comment: Entonces te referias a micro-fronteds para un sitio, eso no es referente a modulos en angular,  digo no de manera estricta de implementacion sino a la idea de formar un conjunto.  Primero crees que sea necesario ese modelo de implementacion para tu sitio?   Con este tipo de modelos agregas independencia pero aumentas complejidad en algunos aspectos, comunicacion entre componentes, que cada equipo en cada micrositio no duplique codigo o componentes, seguridad, si el modulo principal digamos la pagina de inicio esta abajo todo el sitio dejara de funcionar., es necesario saber el requerimiento.

Comment: Así es Miguel, estamos conscientes de lo que comentas.. lo que quisiera es apoyo en la parte técnica.. un proyecto padre que pueda cargar proyectos hijos que puedan replegarse y desplegarse independientemente..